# Kivy: Positioning of text

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to GUI development, and am using [`Kivy`](https://kivy.org/#home) for the same. I have made a `rectangle` at the top of the screen which increases/decreases its length as the size of the window changes. I want to add text inside the rectangle such that when I change the size of the window the text not only increases/decreases its font size but also stays inside the rectangle i.e in the middle. I am not able to figure out how to set the `font` and `position` parameters to achieve my goal.

This is the Myapp.py file code:

```
class Dashboard(RelativeLayout): 
   l = NumericProperty(0.0)
   b = NumericProperty(0.0)


class MyApp(App):  
   def build(self):  
      return (Dashboard())  
MyApp().run()
```

This is my `.kv` file code:

```
<Dashboard>:
l: root.width
b: root.height/7

# creating Canvas 
   canvas: 
       Color: 
          rgba: 216 / 255., 195 / 255., 88 / 255., 1
       Rectangle: 
          pos: (0,self.size[1]/1.15)
          size: (self.l,self.b)


   Label: 
      size: self.parent.size[0], self.parent.size[1]
      font_size: self.parent.size[0] * 0.05
      text_size: self.size
      pos_hint:  {'x':0.5,'y':0.9}
      text:'hello!'
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to make sure the text is centered in the `Rectangle` is to make the `Label` the same size and position of the `Rectangle`, and then use `halign` and `valign`. I have added another `NumericProperty` to the `Dashboard` just to contain the y position of the `Rectangle` and `Label`, so the `Dashboard` class now looks like:

```
class Dashboard(RelativeLayout):
   l = NumericProperty(0.0)
   b = NumericProperty(0.0)
   ypos = NumericProperty(0)
```

And the modified `kv`:

```
<Dashboard>:
    l: root.width
    b: root.height/7
    ypos: root.size[1]/1.15

    # creating Canvas 
    canvas: 
        Color: 
            rgba: 216 / 255., 195 / 255., 88 / 255., 1
        Rectangle: 
            pos: (0, root.ypos)
            size: (root.l,root.b)


    Label: 
        size_hint: None, None
        size: root.l, root.b
        font_size: min(root.size[0] * 0.05, root.size[1] * 0.05)
        text_size: self.size
        halign: 'center'
        valign: 'center'
        pos: 0, root.ypos
        text:'hello!'
```

I also modified the `font_size` calculation so that it considers both the height and width of the `Rectangle`.

Note that if you just want a colored background for the `Label` you can do that within the `Label` itself. Here is another version of the `kv` that does that:

```
<Dashboard>:
    l: root.width
    b: root.height/7
    ypos: root.size[1]/1.15

    Label: 
        canvas.before: 
            Color: 
                rgba: 216 / 255., 195 / 255., 88 / 255., 1
            Rectangle: 
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        size_hint: None, None
        size: root.l, root.b
        font_size: min(root.size[0] * 0.05, root.size[1] * 0.05)
        text_size: self.size
        halign: 'center'
        valign: 'center'
        pos: 0, root.ypos
        text:'hello!'
```